# search for nodes with multiple labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to point neo4j to look for nodes with specific labels not just one label like `(n:Manager)` ? I tired :

```
match(m:Manager {Email: "manager1@gmail.com"}),(n:Scorer {Email: "manager1@gmail.com"})return m, n
```

I want to search for that email the nodes of both types.

This does not work either:

```
match(m:Manager),(n:Scorer) where m.Email = "manager1@gmail.com" or n.Email = "manager1@gmail.com"  return  m
```

Answer (score 2):

if variable input required you can also use the following variant:

```
MATCH (m {Email: 'manager1@gmail.com'})
WHERE 'Manager' in labels(m) AND 'Scorer' in labels(m)
RETURN m
```

Otherwise Christophe's answer is the simpler one:

```
MATCH (m:Manager:Scorer {Email: "manager1@gmail.com"}) RETURN m
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as :

```
MATCH (m:Manager:Scorer {Email: "manager1@gmail.com"}) RETURN m
```